# Configure runner to run multiple jobs at the same time

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When having one gitlab runner serving multiple projects, it can only run one CI pipeline while the other project pipelines have to queue.

Is it possible to make a gitlab runner run pipelines from all projects in parallel?

I don't seem to find anywhere a configuration explanation for this.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I believe the configuration options you are looking for is `concurrent` and `limit`, which you'd change in the GitLab Runners `config.toml` file.

From the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html):

- `concurrent`: limits how many jobs globally can be run concurrently. The most upper limit of jobs using all defined runners. 0 does not mean unlimited
- `limit`:  limit how many jobs can be handled concurrently by this token.

The location for the `config.toml` file:

> - `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` on *nix systems when GitLab Runner is
>   executed as root (this is also path for service configuration)
> - `~/.gitlab-runner/config.toml` on *nix systems when GitLab Runner is
>   executed as non-root
> - `./config.toml` on other systems

Useful [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18224) as well.

Comment: The config is usually found at ```~/etc/gitlab-runner/```

Comment: @SwetankPoddar I'm pretty sure you mean ```/etc/gitlab-runner```, unless you created a ```~/etc/gitlab-runner```to put it in. Otherwise the above sequence of config lookup is correct.

Comment: how one can sets concurrent programmaticaly?

Comment: @IvanBryzzhin First, you obviously need access to the filesystem of the gitlab-runner. It's a toml file. Find some python parser for this format and write a small script to adjust the config file. There should be no need to restart the runner afterwards, according to the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html). (there doesn't seem to be any API for these configs)

Comment: Please note the global concurrent value should be equal to or greater than sum of values of limit in each runner.

Answer (score 2):

On linux system, run the command:
 `$ sudo gedit /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`

than change the value of:
`concurrent = 1`
to another value, for example 2 and save.