# How in gitlab run multiple pipelines in parallel on one machine?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have one machine, and I want multiple pipelines to be run in parallel on that machine.

How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure runner to run multiple jobs at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51828805/configure-runner-to-run-multiple-jobs-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a gitlab-runner setup and working, you should see the following lines at the start of its `config.toml`:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
```

You can run multiple jobs at the same time by adjusting the concurrent value.
[Please check the gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html) for more information

Comment: I have upvoted, but OP actually asks to run multiple *pipelines* (not jobs) in parallel, unless OP confuses pipelines and jobs which are two different things.

Comment: @Igor A runner only executes jobs. Pipelines just schedule the jobs that are available for runners to pick up. Gitlab always runs all pipelines as soon as they are created, but a runner will only run a limited number of jobs at the same time.OP has to confuse the two terms for the question to make any sense.